# Error when styling React components imported from index file, but not when importing directly from component file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, styled-components

Newbie here, so apologies in advance if I am overlooking something obvious or missed a duplicate posting (and also for not posting directly on styled-components, apparently I need a rep for that...) .

The closest I found to my problem was in this resolved issue, at the bottom of the thread: 
 https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/213

The guy had a very similar problem, but the solution was brief and Typescript specific.

BACKGROUND: I have an index file that imports my components from all over, and exports them under a webpack alias.  Whenever I need to import elsewhere I just declare:

```
import { MyComponentA, MyComponentB, MyComponentC } from 'components';
```

I recently started incorporating styled-components into my project and have been getting an error like the following when I try to style components imported in this way:

```
Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined._____________styled-components.browser.esm.js:233
   at new StyledComponentsError (/home/jhillert/Dropbox/Projects/TimeLockr/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:233:59)
   at constructWithOptions (/home/jhillert/Dropbox/Projects/TimeLockr/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:1355:12)
   at styled (/home/jhillert/Dropbox/Projects/TimeLockr/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:2293:11)
   at Module.eval (/home/jhillert/Dropbox/Projects/TimeLockr/src/components/card-area/CardArea.jsx:111:91)
   at eval (/home/jhillert/Dropbox/Projects/TimeLockr/src/components/card-area/CardArea.jsx:133:31)
   at Module../src/components/card-area/CardArea.jsx (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:9343:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:724:30)
   at fn (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:101:20)
   at eval (/home/jhillert/Dropbox/Projects/TimeLockr/src/indexes/components.jsx:17:89)
   at Module../src/indexes/components.jsx (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:9619:1)
```

If I import the component directly from the source file I do not get the error.  It only happens when I try to pass components imported from the index file into the styled() method, and also when I try to use the CSS prop to add inline styling.

For some reason the error does not occur with all components imported in this way, and also I have made changes to my code that suddenly cause the index import to trigger the error.  I really like having a central index file, so a fix would be greatly appreciated.

### Example where css prop causes error:

*Project config below.
Index File looks like this (components.jsx):

```
export { default as ActionBar } from '../components/action-bar/ActionBar';
export { default as AuthForm } from '../components/auth/AuthForm';
export { default as AuthModal } from '../components/auth/AuthModal';
export { default as AuthTabs } from '../components/auth/AuthTabs';
export { default as Box } from '../components/box/Box';

/*==============================================================*/

//CardArea.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  CardColumn  ◀◀◀—————————————— DOES PRODUCE ERROR
  LockedEntryCard,
  ReleasedEntryCard,
} from 'components';

import CardColumn from '../card-column/CardColumn' ◀◀◀——————— DOES NOT

const S = {};

S.CardArea = styled.div`  ◀◀◀————— NOT IMPORTED, NOT A PROBLEM
     /* ommitted */                BUT WOULD CAUSE SAME ERROR 
`;                                 IF IMPORTED.

const CardArea = ({ entries, refresh }) => {
  const { locked, released } = entries;
  const hasLockedChildren = !!(locked.length);
  const hasReleasedChildren = !!(released.length);

  const [showLocked, updateShowLocked] = useState(false);
  const [showReleased, updateShowReleased] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      updateShowLocked(true);
      updateShowReleased(true);
    },
    []);

  return (
    <S.CardArea>
      {(hasReleasedChildren && showReleased)
        && (
          <CardColumn
            id='card-column-released-entries'
            css='                   ◀◀◀ TRIGGERS THE ERROR
              margin-left = 2rem;   ◀◀◀ TRIGGERS THE ERROR
              margin-right = 1rem;  ◀◀◀ TRIGGERS THE ERROR
            '                       ◀◀◀ TRIGGERS THE ERROR
            heading='Unlocked'
            Card={ReleasedEntryCard}

      /* ommitted */

CardArea.propTypes = {
    /* ommitted */
};

export default CardArea;
```

=================================================================

### Webpack configuration (webpack.config.js):

Aliases are towards the bottom.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['react-hot-loader/webpack'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader/locals',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),
  ],
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      // relative path is from src
      { from: './static/favicon.ico' }, // <- your path to favicon
    ]),
    new Dotenv({
      systemvars: true,
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/indexes/components.jsx'),
      contexts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/indexes/contexts.jsx'),
      theme: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/indexes/theme.jsx'),
      utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/indexes/utilities.jsx'),
    },
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

### Babel Config (.bablerc):

```
{
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false
      }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ],
  plugins: [
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source',
    [
      'babel-plugin-styled-components',
      {
        "ssr": false
      }
    ],
  ]
}
```

### Dependencies (Package.json)

```
{
  "name": "timelockr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Making information inaccessible.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/jehillert/Keep-Away"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack -d --mode development",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p --mode production",
    "dev-server": "nodemon --ignore node_modules --inspect server",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --hot --mode development",
    "start:dev": "nodenv -f .",
    "lint:css": "stylelint './src/**/*.js'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.1.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "@material-ui/system": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-alpha.27",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "notistack": "^0.6.1",
    "pbkdf2-password": "^1.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.7.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "async": "^2.6.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^6.22.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint_d": "^7.3.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "node-cmd": "^3.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "^9.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^2.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.6.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `import foo from 'bar'` imports default export while `import {foo} from 'bar'` imports variable foo from file bar.

Comment: In the individual component files, there is only default export.  So I have been leaving the braces off when directly importing without issue.  But the index file exports multiple components under one name.  Aren’t the braces required? Or can I structure the index file in a different that would circumvent the error and still let me use aliases?

Comment: You can use both - it depends how the imported source is created - braces have the same function as destructiong assigment `const {a, b, c} = objWithABCProps` If impoted file have eg. only default export and it's object - using braces import will destruct public props.

Comment: Propably most confusing thing about default export - name in default export doesn't matter - if you default export const foo, you can import bar and it's foo no matter the name, but braces exports are named exports.

Comment: @John so the error only throws when you try to do styled(ImportedComponent) and when u try to call css on a imported component through the index file? In other words just using <ImportedComponent /> gives no issues even when imported through the index file, as long as you don't try to add styles to it?

Comment: @etarhan, yes that is correct.  I have an app I have been working on for the last few months that is my first “all-on-my-own” personal project.  I have 30-40 components that I import this way and never a problem.  I should also mention that if I route UI Library components through the index file this way, the same error occurs.  For example, it happened with Material UI and React-Bootstrap components (I think it was the React-Bootstrap modal...can’t rememeber.  I stopped the index file approach with library components a while ago because it wasn’t worth the effort.).

Comment: @John does my proposed solution fix the issue? As I've mentioned in my answer the consensus seems to be that it is most  likely a circular dependency issue, and moving the component evaluation to occur at runtime seems to help in most cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following github issues from the [arc](https://github.com/diegohaz/arc) repo seem to describe problems similar to the one you are having here: [#339](https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/issues/339), [#130](https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/issues/130). The last issue specifically has [this comment](https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/issues/130#issuecomment-282408542) which suggests a potential solution. By styling in the following manner in most cases the problem is said to be resolved:

```
const StyledCComponent = styled(props => <CComponent {...props} />)``
```

The root underlying cause seem to be a circular dependency issue. By wrapping the component in a function the dependency is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly where a styled component was imported and then styled again w/styled(), but did not help when it came to using the css prop on an imported styled component (I tried applying the solution to the imported component where it was defined).... It's really odd though. I looked back at my files, and I see numerous instances where importing components styled w/styled() via the index file caused no problems. I tried to look for a distinguishing pattern but could not find one.

Comment: Hmm, your solution got me half-way there.  Should I mark it answered or leave open to see if somebody has a suggestion for the css?  Not sure what the StackOverflow expectation is on this...

Comment: It's ultimately up to you, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. As for you css prop issue, you could try to wrap the imported component in another function before using it, or just do `styled(props => <ImportedComponent{...props} />)\`/* new styles here */\``

Comment: @John Glad I could help at least in some way :)

Comment: Yeah, I should probably dig through that stuff some more for future questions.  But I will check this off as answered.  I like having an index file and styled components are great.   Your suggestion let’s me keep both, which is what I wanted. The css part not so important, as I can just use ‘style={{}}’ for inline styling.